# Python skipping elif statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that prints the values and keys in a dictionary depending of the input the user types. The problem appears when the elif statement on line 11 gets skipped. It doesn't matter if the **if** statement is false, the **elif** statement gets skipped. I'm learning so I don't really know where my error is. Thanks for the help!

```
areaM = {str(1) + " acre" : str(160) + " sq rods"}
linearM = {str(1) + " ft" : str(12) + " in", str(1) + " yd": str(3) + " ft"}

def displayConversion(conv):
    for k, v in conv.items():
        print(str(v) + " = " + str(k))
while True:
    print("Enter a conversion")    
    if input() == "Area Meassure":
        displayConversion(areaM)
    elif input() == "Linear Meassure":
        displayConversion(linearM)
    else:
        print("Conversion not available")
```

Comment: Calling `input()` twice creates two input requests with possibly different results. Store the result of the first `input()` in a variable and compare this in the `if ... elif`

Comment: The `elif` statement calls `input()` again, so you're not comparing against the original input value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this as the full code (too much `inputs`s):

```
areaM = {str(1) + " acre" : str(160) + " sq rods"}
linearM = {str(1) + " ft" : str(12) + " in", str(1) + " yd": str(3) + " ft"}

def displayConversion(conv):
    for k, v in conv.items():
        print(str(v) + " = " + str(k))
while True:
    a=input("Enter a conversion\n")    
    if a == "Area Meassure":
        displayConversion(areaM)
        break
    elif a == "Linear Meassure":
        displayConversion(linearM)
        break
    else:
        print("Conversion not available")
```